# Mount disk from Synology/Xpenology with mdadm on Ubuntu

Tags: mount, data-recovery, mdadm

I am moving my data from my Xpenology NAS to a new one. Years ago I had created a single partitions on my NAS and after a couple years the system informed me that one of the disks had a problem and was switched to read only mode.

Now I am moving data by Ubuntu with single disks connected by SATA. Most of the HDDs I managed to mount and copy but I have a problem with one 3TB drive.

When I try `sudo -i`, `apt-get install mdadm` and `mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay` partition does not show up, and I get an error

```
No suitable drives found for /dev/md/5
```

I was creating only single partitions (probably ext4) but Gparted shows   `/dev/sda3`  linux raid. When I checked on Win10 by Diskinternals Linux Reader it also shows 2789,92Gb Raid 1 mirror.

How can I mount it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the next:

- `mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md0 /dev/sda3`
- `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt`

or

- find out what raid devices you have: `ls -l /dev/md/`
- mount it using `mount /dev/md/sp:X /mnt`

[Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300122/mount-a-single-hard-disk-that-was-part-of-raid-1)

Comment: After:                         mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md0 /dev/sda3
I get eroor like this:     mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md0

Comment: Also after mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sda3 --force
Got error: mdadm: /dev/sda3 is busy - skipping

Comment: have you tried `umount /dev/sda3`? Maybe it is mounted somewhere

Comment: /dev/sda3: not mounted.

Comment: I tried again with:  mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay and I got ian info: mdadm: Devices UUID-c281cd92:b7fb783d:cee6be21:34c2f93c and UUID-c281cd92:b7fb783d:cee6be21:34c2f93c have the same name: /dev/md/5
mdadm: Duplicate MD device names in conf file were found.

Comment: `sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda3` - what does it show?

Comment: `sudo mdadm -A -R /dev/md9 /dev/sda3 && sudo mount /dev/md9 /mnt`

Comment: /dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : c281cd92:b7fb783d:cee6be21:34c2f93c
           Name : ServerXpenology:5
  Creation Time : Thu Nov  8 13:47:51 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 1

Comment: Avail Dev Size : 5850889120 (2789.92 GiB 2995.66 GB)
     Array Size : 2925444544 (2789.92 GiB 2995.66 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5850889088 (2789.92 GiB 2995.66 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=32 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5268aa3f:e49e3e57:2fcf6b66:409673e8

    Update Time : Tue Feb 11 11:37:25 2020
       Checksum : be87e053 - correct
         Events : 5


   Device Role : Active device 32768
   Array State : . ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Maybe I didn't mount it but I found a way to copy data to my new NAS.

I had installed in Win 10 RaiDrive, set up sftp network drive automount of my NAS zfs pool and started copying my files by LinuxReader to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on LVM or mdadm but here's what I did to solve a related problem on Ubuntu 18.

A single hard drive SHR attached trough USB-SATA adapter. The system tries to automatically set the RAID volume, but something goes wrong:

If I try to assemble:

```
mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay

mdadm: Found some drive for an array that is already active: /dev/md/DiskStation:2
mdadm: giving up.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

or `mount`:

```
mount /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv /mnt/
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv.
```

I have checked and the system already mapped a `/dev/mdXXX` to the SHR drive. So:

```
dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv

mdadm --stop /dev/mdXXX
```

And after it's possible to retry to assemble with mdadm:

```
mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay
```

The mount reference is under `/media/xxxxx/volumeToMount`